# JS node issue with for and foreach loops

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, foreach, console.log

This is really puzzling me, until 4 days ago everything was working fine and no problems were occurring, but then an issue started when two of my cron daemon jobs stopped working.

I thought nothing of it and decided to rebuild the code and improve it a little as I have gained more insight since the files were coded the first time around.

Here is the problem:

this one works as expected on local machine

```
Object.keys(res).forEach(function(key) {
    const row = res[key];
      client.channels.get(row.forchannel).send({ embed });
      console.log(row.forchannel);
});
```

and so does this one:

```
res.forEach(function(row) {
      client.channels.get(row.forchannel).send({ embed });
      console.log(row.forchannel);
});
```

and also this one:

```
for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
     console.log(res[i]);
     client.channels.get(res[i].forchannel).send({ embed });
}
```

The issue I have is that non of them work when I upload to live server, the results from a MySQL query are there when I console log out of the loop on live, console logging inside the loop on live shows nothing except for the last block of code I posted and this returns one result.

Local machine is windows running Node v11.6 and live is Ubuntu running a v11.12 of node.

So to summary:

On the live server those loops above are not working, I can return arrays when console logging data outside of the loops but on only the last one does any data show when console logging inside the loop.

On local machine everything works as expected, In both cases error catching reports `null` so there are no errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
res.map((result) => {
 client.channels.get(result.forchannel).send({ embed });
});
```

It might help you.

Comment: Thank you, the outcome is exactly the same, just blank, nothing happens on live server no error or anything, a console log inside the block also returns nothing, but again I run it on local machine and it works perfectly..

Comment: are you expecting some result from `client.channels.get(...)` method?

Comment: the expected outcome is that the results from the loop are posted to text channels on discord servers. Server owners subscribe one of their text channels and the id for that is kept in MySQL, queried and then when updates are available the bot will send a message (only if the bot is active on the subscribed server) to the subscribed channel. Hard-coding in channel id's works fine and like i say until a few days everything was ok. `https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/frequently-asked-questions.md#channels-and-guilds`

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what the problem was, although my bot has both a subscribe and an unsubscribe option my code does not cater for the obvious: A discord server Admin deleting a channel, this then leaves a row in the database that when fed into the loop comes back false as the channel no longer exists and stops the auto-posting.

Working code first checks if the channel does actually exist before processing through the array.

```
res.map((result) => {
    if (client.channels.has(result.forchannel)) {
         client.channels.get(result.forchannel).send({ embed });
    }
});
```

`client.channels.has` checks that the channel exists and because its in an if statement will only proceed to post on channels that return true.